# Discord.py task.loop used to change the status in a cog not working

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

from itertools import cycle

status = cycle(['status 1', 'status 2', 'status 3'])

class Example(commands.Cog):


    def __init__(self, dBot):
        self.dBot = dBot
        self.dBot.change_stats.start()

    #EVENTS
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, context, member):
        await context.send(f'Member {member.mention} has joined!')

    #TASKS
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
    async def change_stats(self):
        await self.dBot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))

    #COMMANDS
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, context):
        await context.send("Pong!")

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(self, context, amount=5):
        await context.channel.purge(limit=amount)

def setup(dBot):
    dBot.add_cog(Example(dBot))
```

This is the code above in the cog file where the task is not working correctly, everything else works fine apart from this.

The error that i keep getting is "AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'change_stats'"

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`change_stats` will be an attribute of the `Example` object:

```
self.change_stats.start()
```

Look at the examples in the [Recipes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#recipes) section, where you can find more usages of tasks in cogs.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply been busy with university work, when i do this i get an error that states 'Method 'change_stats' has no 'start' memberpylint(no-member)'

Comment: Update: I put the task in a normal python file instead of a cog and it works perfectly fine by putting change_status.start() in the on_ready function but i cant seem to get it to work in the cog

Answer (score 0):

you have to put "self" in the start() method:  change_status.start(self)
so it will work in cog

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make

```
@client.event()
async def status_task():
   while True:
      await client.change_presence()
      await asyncio.sleep(4)
      await client...
      await asyncio.sleep(4)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('ready')
   client.loop.create_task(status_task())
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to save the bot in an attribute in the constructor to be able to call change_presence in the on_ready method. Works perfectly for me

```
class PresenceCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.change_presence.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=10) 
    async def change_presence(self):
        status = random.choice(self.statuses)
        await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=status))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(PresenceCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your list looks like this**

```
status = cycle (['1','2','3','4'])
```

**And your loop should look like this**

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))
```